# How to import data to Amazon S3 from URL

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and the URL of a large file. I would like to store the content located at the URL in the S3 bucket.

I could download the file to my local machine and then upload it to S3 with Cloudberry or Jungledisk or whatever. However, if the file is large, this may take a long time because the file must be transferred twice, and my network connection is much slower than Amazon's.

If I have a lot of data to store in S3, I can start an EC2 instance, retrieve the files to the instance with curl or wget, and then push the data from the EC2 instance to S3. This works, but it's a lot of steps if I just want to archive one file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can stream the file directly from the source to S3.

If you are using node, you can use [streaming-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaming-s3).

Comment: can i directly load a file to s3 bucket from a web link like from any https link without using ec2 instance in place